# skype - intercepting in coming audio - callback manipulation failed - skypefx

Tags: c#, .net, skype, naudio

In order to intercept external audio that comes in I tried

```
InPort ="3756"

call.set_OutputDevice(TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypePort, InPort.ToString());

// initialized inServer
inServer = new TcpServer(InPort);

inServer.DataReceived += inServer_DataReceived;

// In dataReceived event I tried playing a wav file 
args.Buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\check.wav");
inStream.Write(args.Buffer, 0, args.Buffer.Length);
```

Neither able to hear check.wav nor someway manipulate the incoming audio.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you populating check.wav?

Comment: Hi, It's just a sample pre-recorded file.

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this article that implements a solution for an old version. With small changes it could work:
[DirectSound Capture Using Deviare.](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2009/02/24/directsound-capture-using-deviare/)

Answer (score 0):

IIRIC, skype requires a very specific wav file format and so just trying "standard" wav files will not work - sorry, I am not a sound expert :(

I remember finding a good explanation in [this forum post](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=348961&st=0&p=1590451&#entry1590451), but unfortunately it looks like the [interesting link is broken](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic...t&p=1263521).

Anyway, since I need this information I'll keep trying to find it elsewhere.

Best

Comment: Just asked about that in the skype forums: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=348961&view=findpost&p=2761043

Comment: Hi Vagaus,

Thanks for your response. 16 bit 16kzkHz mono plays fine. I am still not able to intercept incoming audio of Skype :)

Comment: File: WAV PCM
Sockets: raw PCM samples
16 KHz mono, 16 bit  As you know, it is suggested by a skype moderator.

Answer (score 0):

you should see how skypefx does it, capturing stream directly from the memory buffer

here you will find skypefx source
http://skypefx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c1fa20a91a97

from the source you will notice there are various effects that work directly with the memory buffer.